# How to debug my init.el if --debug-init does not help?

Tags: spacemacs, debugging, mu4e

Despite having `--debug-init` in .xinitrc (`exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session emacs --debug-init`), I'm not getting any leading details on this error.

`Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol’s value as variable is void: mu4e-mu-version`

How can I get more informations on the problem?

Comment: Just for the sake of simplicity... is there any reason why you are trying to debug using .xinitrc? Can't you just start Emacs directly from the command line?

And I am not sure what information you are looking for, but the error message says that the variable `mu4e-mu-version` is not yet known when the `dotspacemacs/user-config` gets called (which is more or less he last step in the Spacemacs startup process). Try to comment out the code related to `mu4e` from your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function and see if that variable then is available after startup has finished.

Comment: B.t.w. to get live assistance, better ask on the [Spacemacs gitter channel](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs)

Comment: If you don't see the problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file) then bisect your init file (or `dotspacemacs/user-config`). You can use `comment-region` to comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,... of the file - binary search (quick).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [bug-hunter](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter)? It can automatically detect errors in your `init` file, and when it fails to detect any errors, it helps you isolate the line that triggers it by progressive bisection of the file.